# How can I load a .net native image (NGEN) into multiple appdomains without specifying domain neutrality?

Tags: .net, performance, appdomain, ngen

NGEN + AppDomain problem here.

I'm working on some application changes that revolve around making native images load correctly to prevent awful JIT time in our .net application.  Some parts were easy, but any assemblies that have to load in appdomains (which our app has to use for a variety of reasons) will only load their native image the first time, and on subsequent loads (in what is now a new appdomain) the image is rejected and JIT occurs.

I know all about domain-neutral loading, and have already made use of it for some of our assemblies where it makes sense, but doing domain-neutral loading cancels out one of the major reasons for using appdomains in the first place for us -- as domain neutral images can never be unloaded.

Put succinctly, I need a way to have native images loading and assembly unloading.  I had hoped that the normal restriction wouldn't apply as long as I unloaded the first usage of the native image before I tried to load it again, but this resulted in rejection just like if trying to load the native image concurrently.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx) contains the following quote:

> An alternative approach to falling
>   back to JIT compilation is to load
>   different copies of the native image
>   into every AppDomain that loads the
>   corresponding assembly as
>   domain-specific. However, this
>   approach would require every copy of
>   the NGen image, except for the first,
>   to be loaded at a different address
>   from its preferred base address. Thus
>   all of these copies of the NGen image
>   would need their addresses fixed up.

This would be perfect for my needs, but that article was the only place I've ever seen it mentioned and I am unsure how it would be implemented.

Thanks in advance for any insight, and thanks for looking.

Comment: The tense of *would require* is troublesome.  It reads like "*if* we allowed this then we have to fix up all addresses.  Which is very inefficient so we don't support that".  Call MSFT about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > I had hoped that the normal restriction wouldn't apply as long as I unloaded the first usage of the native image before I tried to load it again, but this resulted in rejection just like if trying to load the native image concurrently.

This works, but you have to wait for the native image to be actually unloaded. When AppDomain.Unload returns, the appdomain is not fully unloaded. The appdomain will get fully unloaded (along with native images) only after next full GC.

> > This MSDN article contains the following quote:

Surupa was speculating about a possible alternative implementation in the CLR but this is not currently implemented.

Thanks
Lakshan Fernando
CLR Team